# AVR, Assembly, Flag V

Tags: assembly, avr, flags

I need advice on an assembler program
(AVR ATMega169). I have to create code to calculate this expression.

```
R20 = (4 * R16 + 3 * R17 - R18) / 8
```

I try to calculate the arithmetic expression in the code and always check the overflow instruction but it doesn't work properly

```
  .org 0
start:
    ldi r16, 10
    ldi r17, 20
    ldi r18, 10
        
    lsl r16
    brvs OVERFLOW

    lsl r16
    brvs OVERFLOW

    mov r20,r17
    brvs OVERFLOW

    lsl r20
    brvs OVERFLOW

    add r20,r17
    brvs OVERFLOW

    add r20, r16
    brvs OVERFLOW

    sub r20,r18
    brvs OVERFLOW

    asr r20
    brvs OVERFLOW

    asr r20
    brvs OVERFLOW

    asr r20
    brvs OVERFLOW
    
    
    brvc OK

    OVERFLOW:
    ldi r30, 0x11

    OK:
    ldi r30, 0x11
konec:
    rjmp konec
```

Comment: Without knowing better, we should consider destroying one of the input variables as bad form.  So, you should copy r16 somewhere before quadrupling.  Also, you're not summing in that 4*R16 calculation prior to dividing by 8.

Comment: are you wanting to deal with overflow on the multiply as well as the add/subtract? being signed if the sign changes then the shift left is an overflow yes?  and for the add/subtract that is done in hardware I hope otherwise it is not to hard to calculate either, what is the real problem here?  can you explain better or show an overflow example that you are not detecting?

Comment: What exactly do you mean *can't* be calculated correctly?  The final value of that expression is guaranteed to fit in an 8-bit register, between `-127` and `+127` for 8-bit signed inputs, so choosing to calculate it in a way that can overflow an intermediate value is up to you.  You *could* just use extra precision (2 registers) for intermediates where necessary instead of checking for overflow after every lsl / add / sub instruction.

Answer (score 2):

As far as properly setting the overflow flag, most of the individual operations will set the overflow flag properly, namely `add`, `sub`, and `lsl`.  How ever, `asr` does not appear to set the overflow flag in a particularly meaningful way regarding signed division.

The problematic thing is that the instructions that do properly set the overflow flag also clear the overflow flag (on success / no overflow), so they either set it or clear it based on that one individual arithmetic operation.  Thus, there appears no direct way to accumulate the overflow condition across multiple instructions.

The solution is to test for overflow after each operation, perhaps by branching to the exit (skipping past the rest of the calculation — leaving garbage as in `R20` though with the overflow flag set.)  Since dividing by 8 cannot overflow, then if you reach that part of the code (i.e. without having overflowed prior calculations), then I would just clear the overflow flag after the division and before reaching the exit.

Another approach would be to `or` the overflow flag after each operation into some variable, then use that variable to set the overflow flag at the end.  This approach would leave a more predictable value in `R20` when overflow does occur, at the expense of additional instructions and variables.

Comment: So if I only had add, sub .. in the calculation, I could use the V flag for every single operation until I came across asr? And may I ask how else should I check the overflow besides the BRVS / BRVC instruction?

Comment: I don't know how else to check the overflow flag on this processor except to branch .  Seems like if you want the value in a register you would use some form of if-then or if-then-else.

Comment: May I ask what the branch in the assembler would look like or where can I study it? Am I getting a little lost in it?

Comment: Not sure what your question is.  Assembly / machine code uses an if-goto-label style for control flow like if-then, while-loop, for-loop.  A conditional branch instruction, such as BRVS needs only one operand, which is a label.  (The overflow flag is implicit in the opcode.)  During its execution, the processor will change the program counter (which tells it what instruction to execute next) conditionally based on the value in the overflow flag: it will either advance the pc normally to the next sequential instruction address or else it will change the pc to equal the branch target address.

Comment: I probably can't express myself well in English. Because the point is that I have no idea how to verify that no overflow has occurred and that the result is correct

Comment: If overflow doesn't occur in any individual operations, then overflow has not occurred in the larger calculation.  Put the other way, if overflow occurs in any of the individual operations, then the whole calculation can be considered having overflowed.

Comment: This is why I suggest to check overflow after each operation, possibly by branching to a label that can report that, or just to the end of the calculation.  Branching somewhere on overflow will not clear the overflow flag, so when the program gets there the overflow flag will still be set on that path, and that seems to be what you're looking for.  The idea is to simply stop the calculation when the overflow flag is set, so you jump to the end with that flag set instead of making an actual answer in `R20`.

Comment: Like I said, by that logic, if the program reaches the divide by 8, then no overflow has occurred so far.  Divide by 8 cannot overflow, so do the `asr`'s; then clear the overflow flag as indicator that the answer is accurate.

Comment: @martin12888: `BRVS handle_overflow` after every instruction *is* how you'd write the branch / check.

Comment: @ErikEidt: To OR the V flag results from every operation, the best way might be to load SREG into a register and OR it into another register (after every operation).  (AVR registers are memory-mapped).  So 2 instructions per operation instead of a BRVS.  When you're done, I guess store back into SREG, so every flag is updated to the OR of any result during the computation.

Comment: Might be less work to compute the whole expression in a way that voids overflow, like with 16-bit add, and 2-register right shift.  The final value of that expression is guaranteed to fit in an 8-bit register, between `-127` and `+127` for 8-bit signed inputs.  Or maybe not, there aren't that many adds / shifts.

Comment: I made adjustments in the code where I check it after each instruction, but I don't think it works properly because in this state the overflow should not occur (if I haven't overlooked), I only have to use 8-bit in the program

Comment: but then for that asr should i delete it?